# Excel Files On Network Drive

Tags: excel, shortcut

The company I work for has one very large master data workbook on a network drive. There are also dozens of smaller "summary" workbooks that link to the master file hosted on the same drive. It's my company's attempt at using Excel as a database system. It is a nightmare to manage.

Anyway, the problem is that the master file is changed several times a day and backed up/renamed every couple of weeks. This means that I need to manually go through the dozens of files and update the links to the new file. For example, I'll have to change "whatever Q3-2010.xls" to "whatever Q4-2011.xls" in dozens of files and hundreds of tabs every few weeks. I'd like to be able to do away with this.

I've had a few ideas, but have ran into problems. Do any of you have any advice on how to simplify this. My previous ideas/problems are:

1. Copy the master file and rename it to "Whatever Current.xls". Do this every time the file changes. The problem with this approach is that several people each change the file several times a day, and somebody is bound to forget.
2. Make a shortcut (symlink) to the master file on the network drive (i.e. put the shortcut on the network drive in the same directory as the master). There are two major problems with this. First, for some reason, I can't seem to create shortcuts on the network drive. I don't know if this is a security issue or just can't be done. Second, when you add a link to a shortcut in Excel, it resolves the file that the shortcut points to and not the shortcut itself. This is no better than what we have now.
3. Rename the master file to "Whatever Current.xls" This seems the simplest and should work perfectly. Unfortunately company policy requires a date or quarter identifier in the file-name.

So now that you see my problem, does anybody have any ideas on how to best achieve this?
Thanks!

EDIT: Spelling

EDIT2: Once again, I ran into a snag. I've created the abstraction file with the links, but I can't actually use those as references from the other files. I've looked around and it looks like I have to to use the INDIRECT and CONCATENATE functions for this. Unfortunately, INDIRECT only works with open workbooks, and I assumed that the abstraction file would be closed. There are several Excel "extensions" that I can use to allow INDIRECT to work on a closed workbook, but since this has to work for everybody, that's not an option. My only option right now is to make the abstraction file, then make links to the file in each of the files that reference it, then use INDIRECT as a reference to the reference to the links (this is getting complicated). Does anybody have any other ideas?

EDIT3: Actually, my idea above does not work. The link evaluated must still be open (in my case it's the master data sheet) and we can't assume that it is. I'm starting to think that maybe I should use some VBA to run a query or something, but I don't know how to do that? Any help?

Comment: A shotgun to the designer's head would be a start, followed by a complete re-engineering from the ground up.

Comment: Well... the designer is my boss. I'm just the maintainer and updater.

Comment: Maybe an abstraction layer - store filenames in another spreadsheet and have all your other spreadsheets load filenames from that new spreadsheet. Then you've only got a set of cell addresses, rather than filenames. As long as no one moves filenames around, it should relieve some of the short-term pain.

Comment: That's actually a great idea! I was also thinking of maybe using some VBA to replace the file links in all the files, but your idea is a lot simpler. I'll test it to see how it works. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm having some trouble. See EDIT2 and EDIT3 in the question. There always seems to be some arbitrary limitation in Excel that stop whatever I try to do.

Comment: maybe some macros to force the abstraction file to be opened? Or maybe put the file data into a database instead and use excel's query support to retrieve it that way.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I was hoping to avoid the database route, but I see that there may not be a choice. I was actually thinking of using a macro to query (SQL-style) the abstraction file for the links, then using INDIRECT and CONCATENATE to "build" the references, but that seems like too much work for what amounts to a simple "patch". I'll keep looking around.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the master worksheet with an event that will automatically also save the backup  (which you mentioned you'd be afraid people would forget), that way it's impossible for it not to be saved and not backed up under the same name you need it to be plus remoes the work fr people editing the file.

Explore using the workbook_beforesave event - this will kick off every time the user attempts to save the workbook. Disable prompts and stealthily save the backup under the name you need it to be! Don't forget to turn off events during the code or your backup save will trigger the event as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use VBA to update the links when necessary, at least until you can convince them to refactor the process.  In every child workbook, put a CustomDocumentProperty named Source and set it's value to the full path of the Source file.  We'll use the existence of this property to determine if we're dealing with a child workbook.  In a new add-in, insert a class module with this code

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents mobjApp As Application

Public Property Get App() As Application: Set App = mobjApp: End Property
Public Property Set App(ByVal objApp As Application): Set mobjApp = objApp: End Property

Private Sub mobjApp_WorkbookOpen(ByVal wb As Workbook)

    Dim sOldSource As String, sNewSource As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    If IsChild(wb) Then 'only work with child workbooks, event fires for every workbook
        sOldSource = GetSource(wb) 'read the customdocprop
        If Len(Dir(sOldSource)) = 0 Then 'if the file doesn't exist, we need to update the links

            'get the new source file
            sNewSource = Application.GetOpenFilename("*.xlsx, *.xlsx", , "Select New Source", , False)

            'change the link source
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                wb.ChangeLink sOldSource, sNewSource, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

In a standard module (I call mine MUtilities) put this code

```
Option Explicit

Private Const msDOCPROP As String = "Source"

Function IsChild(wb As Workbook) As Boolean

    Dim sSource As String

    On Error Resume Next
        sSource = wb.CustomDocumentProperties(msDOCPROP)
    On Error GoTo 0

    IsChild = Len(sSource) > 0

End Function

Function GetSource(wb As Workbook) As String

    On Error Resume Next
        GetSource = wb.CustomDocumentProperties(msDOCPROP)

End Function
```

In another standard module (MOpenClose) put this code

```
Option Explicit

Public gclsAppEvents As CAppEvents

Sub Auto_Open()

    Set gclsAppEvents = New CAppEvents

    Set gclsAppEvents.App = Application

End Sub
```

When the add-in is loaded, it will create a new CAppEvents that will listen for workbook open events.  Every time a workbook opens, it will check to see if it's relevant.  If it is, it will see if the source file still exists.  If not, it will prompt to select the new source file and update the links.

You may need to tweak the logic and you'll definitely want to make the error handling more robust.

Once you get this working, start writing the code that ports this information into an Access (or other) database.